Any wood fillers for vinyl floor joints / click-locks that have partially separated?
I would like to provide cosmetic repair on a flooring section for which occasional joints have separation - and the click-locks are visible. The goal would be to cover the joints with the minimum of fuss / noticeability.

Is a standard wood filler - maybe compressed into the narrow groove with a putty knife - the way to go?  I'm concerned it would not hold. Is there any compound of reddish-oak color that would be durable and adhere to this?

Do the seams move(open/close)?  If they move maybe one of those scratch fillers/wax pens.  If they do not move then wood filler should work.  Most come in different colours.

The seams are rigid in place  structurally the floor is ok  But those spots are eyesores

Finding the right colour match is the hardest.  Not sure if they have small sample sizes to try out, before buying a small can.

@crip659  Turns out HomeDepot has exactly the right stuff - even specifically for fixing/filling wood vinyl planks.  But yea getting the color match was not in the cards: they have beige and shades of brown but not the reddish/orange-isg-tint of this pretty stuff I have.  I chose a dark beige and will see how well it works out.
